# Progress bar over two Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'd like to have a kind of overall progress bar for two parallel running `Thread` instances.

Unfortunately I'm not able to make it. Can somebody give me any hint?

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadItems(Parent);
                    }
                });
                t.start();
                 
                Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        loadItems(Parent2);
                    }
                });
                r.start();

                dmf.getFrame().dispose();
            }
        });
```

Comment: *"Can somebody give me any hint?"* Not sure if hint or tips.. but 1) Post a [mre]. 2)  A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Use two progress bars.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) will show you how to use a progress bar for one javax.swing.Thread.  You'll have to decide how the progress bar should move when there are two Threads.